# set ProxyAuthorizationPolicy for CXF httpConduit doesn't work

Tags: java, proxy, cxf

I'm Using **CXF** 3.1.5, I'm trying to make it work with **proxy**. if there is no username and password for the proxy, then it works; if there is an username and password for the proxy, then it doesn't work. here is my code:

```
//to create my own http conduit
bus.setExtension(new TLSAndProxySupportedHTTPConduitFactory(settings, HTTPConduitFactory.class);
//to get wsdl definition
Definition definition = bus.getExtension(WSDLManager.class).getDefinition(uri);
```

TLSAndProxySupportedHTTPConduitFactory implements **HTTPConduitFactory**, and will create a TLSAndProxySupportedHTTPConduit which extends **URLConnectionHTTPConduit**, in TLSAndProxySupportedHTTPConduit, here is the related code for proxy settings:

```
            //HTTPClientPolicy settings works
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setProxyServer(proxy.getHostName());
        httpClientPolicy.setProxyServerPort(proxy.getPort());

        this.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        if (proxy.getUserName() != null) {
            //ProxyAuthorizationPolicy settings doesn't work
            this.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName(proxy.getUserName());
            this.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword(proxy.getPassword());

        }
```

Please do remember if the proxy has no username and password, everything works just fine.and if the target URL for loading WSDL definition is started with https(https is required for me), the proxy doesn't work. if it's started with http, then the proxy with username and password works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution:
The Reason is

> The Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) library from Sun Microsystems lets you access a secure Web server from behind a firewall via proxy tunneling. To do this, the JSSE application needs to set the https.ProxyHost and https.ProxyPort system properties. The tunneling code in JSSE checks for "HTTP 1.0" in the proxy's response. If your proxy, like many, returns "HTTP 1.1", you will get an IOException. In this case, **you need to implement your own HTTPS tunneling protocol**.

Referance:http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077475/core-java/java-tip-111--implement-https-tunneling-with-jsse.html
and https://community.oracle.com/thread/1534538

Then you could overwrite method setupConnection of URLConnectionHTTPConduit.

```
@Override
protected void setupConnection(Message message, Address address, HTTPClientPolicy csPolicy) throws IOException {
    super.setupConnection(message, address, csPolicy);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) message.get(KEY_HTTP_CONNECTION);
    decorateHttpsURLConnection((HttpsURLConnection) connection);\
    message.put(KEY_HTTP_CONNECTION, connection);
}
```

in the method decorateHttpsURLConnection:

```
httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLTunnelSocketFactory(getProxy(), sslContext.getSocketFactory()));
```